# Why don't my iptables log?

Tags: 16.04, server, iptables, log, logging

I have a linux server running on Ubuntu 16.04. Today I installed PSAD, a Intrusion Detection System.

PSAD works by analyzing the logfiles of iptables. So, first thing to do before using PSAD is enabling logging of iptables.

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -j LOG
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -j LOG
```

I ran a port scan and called the PSAD status afterwards. It should display that a port scan occured, but nothing was displayed. Just that there haven't been a port scan yet.

After some time I realized, iptables isn't logging. No log-file has iptables logs in it. I looked into

- `/var/log/messages`, where they should be in by default, but the file is empty
- `/var/log/kern.log`
- `/var/log/syslog`

There is nothing. Maybe it is worth noting that I use UFW. I followed a [tutorial about PSAD and UFW](https://gist.github.com/netson/c45b2dc4e835761fbccc), but still nothing happens. No logs in the new files, created in the tutorial either.

What could be the reason? I haven't set up the server on my own. The most important securings have been done before me. Maybe they have removed some packages. It would be great if you could help me, the server has to be secure.

Comment: The log rule only applies if no other rule applied before... maybe there are other rules already handling packages and causing to leave the chain before they reach the log rules?

Comment: Glad to help you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rules in IP tables get applied from top to bottom.

Anytime a rules applies to a package it is handled as the rule defines and (if not configured different) causes to leave the rule chain.

This means if your LOG rule is placed below other rules, it will only apply to packages which where NOT handled by the rules before.

If instead you want to LOG every package, place the LOG rule on top of the acchording rule chain.

By the way:
The default logfile for iptables is in `/var/log/kern.log`

Answer (score 2):

Probably kernel logging is disabled in (r)syslog.
Add this in /etc/rsyslog.conf file:  `kern.warn /var/log/firewall.log` and reload syslog.

After, make some rule like, `iptables -A -p tcp --dport 22 -j LOG --log-prefix " ALERT " --log-level=warning`

And scan your SSH port.

Answer (score 1):

Uncomment the line in `/etc/rsyslog.conf`:

```
module(load="imklog") # provides kernel logging support
```

Then run

```
service rsyslog restart
```

Check the log using

```
tail -f /var/log/syslog
```

OR:

```
date; stat /var/log/syslog
```

Comment: Thank you! Other solutions did not work